# how do i fix syntax error in Python shell script?

Tags: python, syntax, compiler-errors, python-3.9

after say i typed the following code:

```
class Students:
...   def _init_(self, name, age, grade)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    def _init_(self, name, age, grade)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

i am unable to go back and fix the syntax error and have to start all over again.
i am using the Python 3.9 shell script while learning python for the first time so i dont know how to go about this.

like any other time you code, I tried going back to the previous line using the arrow keys or my cursor and using backspace to fix the error or just adding the missing colon. It doesn't work for me, but the course I'm learning from, the guy seems to be able to do this somehow.

Comment: yes, i know what my error is. This is just an example to show that once i get an error im not able to fix it within the same line of code

Comment: You'll need to add ":" at the end of that line to define a function, I think that's what the error trying to tell you

Comment: Bods, I think he knows what the *problem* is, it's just that he though he could fix it by retyping just the dunder-init line. That won't work directly in the Python interpreter (or IDLE, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You have to retype the *entire* definition, *both* lines rather than just the `__init__` definition line. That's because you were in the middle of defining the `Student` class when the error occurred, so *none* of it was complete.

However, it will go far easier on you if you create the whole thing in your favourite editor and then just pass that to the Python interpreter. That way, you'll only have to retype small bits.

That will prevent you from cursing and pulling your hair out if that class is some 40-line thing and you make an error on the 39th line :-)

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said, the basic Python shell is very limited and you'll be much better off using an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download), [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/), etc. Another option is something like the [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/), which you can even use online without downloading anything.

As an extra, if you still want/need to use a Python shell instead, I recommend using [iPython](https://ipython.org/install.html), which allows you to do what you're looking for (navigate back with arrow keys and edit previous inputs).